# logic when evaluating permissions for a shared resource in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I'm having trouble understanding the logic when evaluating permission for a shared resource.

- Alice creates the resource `aliceResource` with the scopes `read, create, delete`
- Alice creates the policy `isAdmin` that verifies if a user is `admin`
- Alice creates a permission that applies the policy `isAdmin` to the resource `aliceResource`
  [image: isAdmin permission]
- Alice shares the resource `aliceResource` with the scope `read` to the user `Bob`
  [image: Alice shares with bob]

---

### Evaluating permissions

- For `aliceResource` in the scope `read` for bob with no role assigned.
  [image: evaluate read]
  Question 1. Why is it ignoring the policy `isAdmin` that is applied to the resource ?
  [image: result read]
- For `aliceResource` in the scope `delete` for bob
  [image: evaluate delete]
  Question 2. When bob has no role assigned, why the policy resource owner is granting `read` even though I'm evaluating for the scope `delete` ?
  [image: no role]
  Question 3. When bob has the role `admin`, why is it the result **permit** ?, Alice shared the resource with `bob` for `read` not `delete`
  [image: role admin]

I would appreciate if someone could help me understand what's going on.

Thanks

---

Edit 1.
I have my client evaluation strategy set to **unanimous**, what I would expect is for all the policies to apply but if I evaluate for a user that has role admin with whom the resource has not been shared, the decision is grant, how can I make the client enforce all the policies ?

Right now the client is doing an **or** between my policies and the policies created by keycloak when the resource is shared.

[image: grant]

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak did not crystal clear documentation for grant decisions.
This diagram is my understanding. The key is **Client Decision Strategy**
if set **Affirmative**, will **OR** logic.
if set **Unanimous**, will **AND** logic.
I made my own permissions(read, delete, and create) and policies. Each permission has a single scope (read, delete, or create). Bob assigned read policy, admin assigned all three policies. The permission decision strategy does not affect in this case (due to single assigned between permission and scope)

If set it with **Disabled**, any users can access the aliceResource.

[image]

This affects two cases by set **client decision strategy**. for bob
[image]

This affects two cases by set **client decision strategy**. for admin
[image]

So, if you want to allow bob only read scope and admin three scopes, the client decision should be **Affirmative**

This is my test decision results.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just added an edit to my post, the problem that I'm having is that I need the client to enforce all the policies, I have my client evaluation policy set to `unanimous`. but the evaluation is doing an **or** between the policies that I created and the policy created by keycloak when the resource is shared.

Comment: @kronolynx, Oh you missed vote to me.