# How to get the password expired date of a user in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I now using Keycloak 18.0.1.

When the user log in my system by Keycloak, I want to know exactly when the password will be expired.
For your information, I'm using keycloak-angular and keycloak-js

I have searched on https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_passwordpolicytyperepresentation but it doesn't have an API that suit my need

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A password not expired. it just temporary or not. I think you looking for something else. can you confirm it?

Comment: @BenchVue We have setup a password policy for users must update their password after a specific time and I want to get the date that user need to update the password

Comment: That was time based policy. It is not default. see this [link](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/authorization_services/topics/policy/time-policy.html). Still password is not expired. It is check the time period, if expired policy to deny to access the resource.

Comment: So you want to get the expire date for specific policy?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the expire date for a specific policy

Comment: OK, I will try in Today's night. Give me a time.

Comment: OK, I made my answer, can you review it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very detail answer, it help me to solve the problem

Comment: I am happy to hear to address your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API can get the detail of Policy.

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/policy/{policy-uuid}
```

Example

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/test/clients/246d7abb-da85-420b-92b4-65b1b3d287c1/authz/resource-server/policy/04dbe6e9-a1d3-449a-b001-42eab0eb51e6
```

Result

```
{
    "id": "04dbe6e9-a1d3-449a-b001-42eab0eb51e6",
    "name": "policy1",
    "description": "short term license",
    "type": "time",
    "logic": "POSITIVE",
    "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
    "config": {
        "noa": "2023-03-02 12:35:45",
        "nbf": "2022-01-02 01:02:06"
    }
}
```

This result get this UI information

Example : time based policy can get the time period.

#### Overview

In left side, setup order by UI

In Right side, get information by API call
I think you interest blue circle #10.

I will demo user can access the resource by time base policy.
Example, the license control by time period.

[image: Overview]

#### UI setup

[image: UI setup]

#### API

I am using Keycloak v18.0.1 (if use v19/v20, just remove auth in API endpoint)

Get User

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{user-uuid}
```

Get Client

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}
```

Get Resource list

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/resource/
```

Get Resource

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/resource/{resource-uuid}
```

Get Permissions & Policy list

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/policy
```

Example by Postman -
You can see the time period information - red box

[image]

Get policy of specific permission

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/policy/{permission-uuid}/associatedPolicies
```

[image]

User mapped into policy

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/policy/{policy-uuid}
```

The user list will return in body of response

```
{
    "id": {policy-uuid},
    "name": {policy-name},
    "config": {
        "users": "[array of {user-uuid}]"
    }
}
```

[image]

#### Evaluate by UI

[image]

Result -
*note permission's Decision Strategy -

#1 Unanimous (AND - policy1 and policy 2) then Permit

#2 Affirmative(OR - policy1 or policy 2) then Permit

[image]

If make expired policy

[image]

, will be deny - due to AND condition

[image]

#### Evaluate by API

```
POST {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/policy/evaluate
```

In body

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": <resource-name>,
      "owner": {
        "id": <client-uuid>,
        "name": <client-name>
      },
      "ownerManagedAccess": false,
      "_id": <resource-uuid>,
      "uris": [],
      "scopes": []
    }
  ],
  "context": { "attributes": {} },
  "roleIds": [],
  "clientId": <client-uuid>,
  "userId": <user-uuid>,
  "entitlements": false
}
```

Evaluate by Postman
[image]

Result

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "resource": {
                "name": "resource1",
                "_id": "3cb04615-ed9f-42a6-ab77-4254bf470891"
            },
            "scopes": [],
            "policies": [
                {
                    "policy": {
                        "id": "8597a6b3-ba5f-4849-9987-9a57b2f3db90",
                        "name": "permissions1",
                        "type": "resource",
                        "resources": [
                            "resource1"
                        ],
                        "scopes": [],
                        "logic": "POSITIVE",
                        "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
                        "config": {}
                    },
                    "status": "DENY",
                    "associatedPolicies": [
                        {
                            "policy": {
                                "id": "6b2a4cce-f6ba-48eb-a8d4-ee3aad88c677",
                                "name": "policy-user",
                                "type": "user",
                                "resources": [],
                                "scopes": [],
                                "logic": "POSITIVE",
                                "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
                                "config": {}
                            },
                            "status": "PERMIT",
                            "associatedPolicies": [],
                            "scopes": []
                        },
                        {
                            "policy": {
                                "id": "04dbe6e9-a1d3-449a-b001-42eab0eb51e6",
                                "name": "policy1",
                                "description": "short term license",
                                "type": "time",
                                "resources": [],
                                "scopes": [],
                                "logic": "POSITIVE",
                                "decisionStrategy": "UNANIMOUS",
                                "config": {}
                            },
                            "status": "DENY",
                            "associatedPolicies": [],
                            "scopes": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "scopes": []
                }
            ],
            "status": "DENY",
            "allowedScopes": []
        }
    ],
    "entitlements": false,
    "status": "DENY",
    "rpt": {
        "exp": 1677207180,
        "iat": 1677206880,
        "jti": "c0f813e4-eff1-4c4a-9c65-4cc31fcc54a8",
        "aud": "my-test",
        "sub": "fd3d621a-565c-4dfb-b476-b605faadd798",
        "typ": "Bearer",
        "azp": "my-test",
        "session_state": "45f5a765-e95f-48cb-95ea-36e4a6ca22a0",
        "acr": "1",
        "allowed-origins": [
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ],
        "realm_access": {
            "roles": [
                "default-roles-test",
                "offline_access",
                "uma_authorization"
            ]
        },
        "resource_access": {
            "account": {
                "roles": [
                    "manage-account",
                    "manage-account-links",
                    "view-profile"
                ]
            }
        },
        "authorization": {
            "permissions": []
        },
        "scope": "email profile",
        "sid": "45f5a765-e95f-48cb-95ea-36e4a6ca22a0",
        "email_verified": true,
        "preferred_username": "user1",
        "email": "user1@test.com"
    }
}
```

#### References

[how to get all keycloak users who can access to a specific resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74603719/how-to-get-all-keycloak-users-who-can-access-to-a-specific-resource/74605464#74605464)

[logic when evaluating permissions for a shared resource in keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403184/logic-when-evaluating-permissions-for-a-shared-resource-in-keycloak/64419456#64419456)

Answer (score 0):

There is not an API endpoint that gives that information directly, but it can be calculated by using the password policy and the password creation date.

Reference

https://medium.com/@lejdiprifti/expiration-date-of-users-password-in-keycloak-389566d5d78c